# Disable link functionality for certain products in Category View? (Magento)

Tags: magento, hyperlink, product, clickable, catalog

Disable link functionality for certain products in Category View?

I only want some product to be visible in category, not clickable!

See example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v97gS.jpg I want only product in stock to be clickable.

How to do that? Step by step will be nice. Thanks.

Comment: See example: http://i.imgur.com/m3ZHp1G.jpg I want only product in stock to be clickable. Please help me how to do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigate to

`app/design/frontend/<package_name>/<theme_name>/template/catalog/product/list.phtml`

else copy this file from base/default theme to your theme

Goto this line
                    `<h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_productNameStripped; ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName() , 'name'); ?></a></h2>`

Add your condition before it

Comment: What is this condition and how it works with certain products?

Comment: here the products are in href tag so they are clickable

So with your neccesary condition change the code to make it clikable or not

Comment: Ok, i know how to do that. But i need to disable link funkcionality for certain products only, not for all.. in product category.

Comment: See example: http://i.imgur.com/m3ZHp1G.jpg I want only product in stock to be clickable.